# stm32cube, usb host, hid mouse/keyboard

Tags: usb, host, hid, stm32f4

I've been trying to set up some basic usb comunication with a usb mouse using my stm32f4 discvery. there are no usb examples for my board so I went in to look at other boards.

stm's Cube library thingy promissed easy development and all, so I generated a project with cube inlcuding USB_OTG_FS in host only mode and four IO pins for LED's.
I had a look in the files and it seemed like reading mouse buttons would be fairly trivial, but I can't make it work.
if I run

```
devtype = USBH_HID_GetDeviceType(&hUsbHostFS);
```

it detects the device correctly.

```
USBH_HID_MouseInit(&hUsbHostFS)
```

returns USBH_OK,
but no matter what I try

```
mouse=USBH_HID_GetMouseInfo(&hUsbHostFS);
```

is always NULL

"USBH_HID_MouseInit" is never mentioned in the documentation(DM00105256.pdf)
also, only the RTOS examples use them. Reading the usb host standalone example, it would seem that to comunicate with a mouse would be as simple as runing GetDeviceType, and poll GetMouseInfo, but I can't get it to work.

this is all the code I added, it's executed in the main while

```
 if(Appli_state == APPLICATION_READY){
    switch(state)
    {
    case 0:

          devtype = USBH_HID_GetDeviceType(&hUsbHostFS);
           if(devtype == HID_MOUSE){
               HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD,GPIO_PIN_14,1);
               HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD,GPIO_PIN_12,0);
               state=1;
           }
           else if(devtype == HID_KEYBOARD){
               HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD,GPIO_PIN_14,0);
               HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD,GPIO_PIN_12,1);
               state=2;
           }
           else{
               HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD,GPIO_PIN_14,0);
               HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD,GPIO_PIN_12,0);
           }

    break;

    case 1:
        if(USBH_HID_MouseInit(&hUsbHostFS)==0){
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD,GPIO_PIN_15,1);
            state=3;
        }
        else {
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD,GPIO_PIN_15,0);
            state=0;
        }

    break;

    case 3:
        mouse=USBH_HID_GetMouseInfo(&hUsbHostFS);
        if(mouse != NULL)HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD,GPIO_PIN_13,1);
        else HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD,GPIO_PIN_13,0);

    break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    }
    if(Appli_state != APPLICATION_READY) state=0;
```

rest of the code is unchanged. like I said before it detects the connection and if it's a mouse, keyboard or unknown device just fine. I just can't get it to communicate

Answer (score 0):

The Cube is buggy, coded in a strange way, and not well documented.

Depending on the actual board you have, you must make sure the clocks are setup correctly (in system_stm32f4.c)

With the stm32f407-based version (http://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/stm32f4discovery.html) you should use these settings:

```
HSE = 8000000
PLL_M = 8
PLL_Q = 7
PLL_N = 336
PLL_P = 4
```

The USB OTG FS requires a 48MHz clock. Here are the equations:

```
USB OTG FS, SDIO and RNG Clock =  PLL_VCO / PLLQ
PLL_VCO = (HSE_VALUE / PLL_M) * PLL_N
```